# How can I use my Google API email @developer.gserviceaccount.com

Tags: google-app-engine, email

This is simple question for those who know.
I have Google API registered access and as part of it
I was given few email addresses (@developer.gserviceaccount.com),
One per each type of access.
It seems that the main purpose of those email addresses, is to be a distinguishing ids.
My question is if its possible to use those email addresses as real mailboxes?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not destined to be used as email addresses, think of them more as user_id's for different purposes.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) you can see an example os the @developer.gserviceaccount.com

I guess I'm a bit late for this answer but I am currently facing some issues with this subject so I think it might be useful to someone.